# Count spaces from text file to find its word count

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I want to create an application that reads from a text file with multiple lines of words. 
It will output the wordcount by counting the number of spaces between the words and adding a correction factor.

I'm not sure what input methods to use to do this. 
My output with the current code is not correct. It will not count the words after the first and it does not count spaces at all.

How can I fix it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader( "/input5.txt"));//file read


    System.out.println("Echo print of the input file is " + in.nextLine());

    int i = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    String a = in.next();
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {

        while (i < a.length()) {
            if (a.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                counter++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;

    }

    int wordcount = (counter + 1);
    System.out.println("The word count is " + wordcount);
}
```

> bet Aiwegfu24r;q0912j cold jus not Money Nil Nelzik1-aj
>
> 129puehilhwueildgyuol

That the input file.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int count = 0;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader( "/input5.txt"));//file read
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {

            System.out.println("echo print of the input: " + in.nextLine());
            in.reset();
        }

        while (in.hasNext()) {

            count++;
            in.next();

        }
        System.out.println("The word count is " + count);

    }
```

That's the new code.

Comment: Remove `String a = in.next();` and add, inside the first while, `String a = in.nextLine();`

Comment: output is 1 if I do that

Comment: Please, update your code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default delimiter for Scanner.next() is whitespace. Each time you call next(), your program is stripping the whitespace and returning a "word." Hence, you might find your problem easier if you simply count the number of times next() is called:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(dir + "/input5.txt"));
int count = 0;

while (in.hasNext()) {
    count++;
    in.next();
}
```

Also, note that you are calling nextLine() prior to initializing your counting loop. Scanner objects have an internal buffer, and any time you call next() or nextLine(), the cursor for that buffer moves ahead. You need to remove the calls to nextLine() from your program, or you need to reinitialize your Scanner.

If you want to output file contents (as it appears you do), simply do something like this:

```
System.out.println("File contents:");
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(in.nextLine());
}
in = new Scanner(new FileReader(dir + "/input5.txt"));
//now you can do your counting, as the buffer has been reset
```

Comment: the count output is 1 if I try that

Comment: what gets discarded if I call next() first?

Comment: I wanted the application to print out the input and then the word count. This results in a word count of 0. I updated the question with the new code,

Comment: fixed, I don't need help on this question anymore.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. reset() wasn't working the way I expected it to, my bad.

Comment: if one is restricted to while loops and scanners, this is the most widely used  and simplest method to solve this problem?

Comment: I would imagine so. The way you were initially attempting seemed rather convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
int count = 0;
while (in.hasNextLine())
    count += in.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+").length;
```

The regex in the split consumes multiple spaces if they occur, giving you the correct number of words no matter the spacing.

The call to trim removes leading spaces if they exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use -

```
public static int wordCount(String s) {
    int counter = 0;
    s = s.trim(); //edit

    for (int i = 0; i <= s.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {
            counter++;
            for (; i <= s.length() - 1; i++) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

        }

    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Same issue. Doing `s.trim()` will **not** change `s`, as strings are immutable. You need to reassign `s`. `s = s.trim()`